# How will the coefficient of independent variable change when fixed effects assumption is used?

Tags: fixed-effects-model

I think coefficient of all independent variables should change in same direction, if a fixed effect assumption is used, the following are my results. They change in different direction, what's the problem? By the way, when I add one more control variable (agglomeration effect), the coefficient also change in different direction. It's weird.
    [image]

Comment: Indicate your dependent variable.

Comment: please explain fixed effect assumption.